# Making a pin for my bar using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw this picture:

[image]

I have done this so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
                    every node/.style={ outer sep = 0pt,
                                        thick},
                    place/.style={  circle,
                                    fill=gray!20,
                                    thick,
                                    inner sep=0pt,
                                    minimum size=6mm}
                    ]
%% Setting a few styles
\tikzstyle{spring}=[decorate,
                    decoration={zigzag,
                                pre length=0.3cm,
                                post length=0.3cm,
                                segment length=6,
                                amplitude=6}
                    ]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,
                    decoration={markings,
                                mark connection node=dmp,
                                mark=at position 0.5 with {\node (dmp) [thick,
                                                                        inner sep=0pt,
                                                                        transform shape,
                                                                        rotate=-90,
                                                                        minimum width=15pt,
                                                                        minimum height=3pt,
                                                                        draw=none] {};
                                                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2.5pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
                                                            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
                                                            }
                                },
                     decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,
                    pattern=north east lines,
                    draw=none,
                    minimum width=0.3cm,
                    minimum height=0.3cm]
\tikzstyle{bar}=[fill=lightgray,
                draw=black,
                minimum width=6cm,
                minimum height=0cm,
                anchor=west]

%% Drawing start
\node (Bar) [bar, minimum height=0.001cm] at (0,0) {};
\draw[->] (10:2.5) arc[start angle=10, delta angle=-20, radius=3.5] node[anchor=west]{$\theta$};
\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,minimum height=0.8cm] at ( -0.3,0.4) {};
\node[anchor=east] at (ground.west) {$O$};
\draw (ground.north east) -- (ground.south east);
\draw (0,0) [ fill=lightgray, very thick,domain=-90:90] plot ({cos(\x)/2}, {sin(\x)/2}) --cycle;
\draw [spring] (Bar.north) -- node[anchor=north,xshift=0.5cm]{$k_1$} +(0,2) node(EndSpring1){};
\node (ground1) [ground,anchor=south,minimum width=0.8cm] at (EndSpring1) {};
\draw (ground1.south east) -- (ground1.south west);
\draw [spring] (Bar.east) -- node[anchor=east,xshift=-0.3cm]{$k$} +(0,-2) node(EndSpring){};
\node (m) [bar,anchor=north, minimum height=0.8cm,minimum width=1cm] at (EndSpring) {$m$};
\draw[dash dot] (m.east) -- ($(m.east)+(0.75cm,0)$) node(xaxis){};
\draw[thick,->] (xaxis.center) -- +(0,-1cm)node[near end,anchor=west]{$x$};
\draw[dash dot] (m.south) -- ($(m.south)+(0cm,-0.75)$) node(ldimension1){};
\draw[dash dot] (ground.south east) -- ($(ground.south east)+(0cm,-3)$) node(ldimension2){};
\draw[<->] ($(ldimension1.south)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(ldimension2.south)+(0,0.5)$) node[midway,anchor=south]{$\ell$};
\draw[dash dot] (Bar.south) -- ($(Bar.south)+(0cm,-2)$) node(adimension){};
\draw[<->] ($(ldimension2.south)+(0,2.5)$) -- ($(adimension.south)+(0,0.5)$) node[midway,anchor=south]{$a$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and i got this:

[image]

But there's some problem:

1.Pin looks awkward.

2.Dimensions looks crooked.

3.Bar is so thick.

I need HELP!!!

Comment: The pin is the thing on the left end of the bar?

Comment: For 3, modify the `inner sep` of the node. It's 0.333em by default I think, set `inner sep=0pt` and the `minimum height` key may be more predictable.

Comment: Yes that is the pin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my best guess on drawing the pin: the outer "thing" doesn't look like a perfect half-circle, it looks like it is stretched a bit in x-direction. We can do that too, fill it white, and add a small blue circle inside it. Finally, move the ground a bit closer, so they touch like in the reference image

```
\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,minimum height=0.8cm] at ( -0.15,0.4) {};
...
\draw (0,0) [ fill=white, very thick,domain=-90:90] plot ({cos(\x)*8pt}, {sin(\x)*6pt});
\node[circle, draw, fill=blue, inner sep=2pt,anchor=east] at ($(Bar.west)+(6.5pt,0)$) {};
```

Then, the diagram looks crooked, because the measurements `a` and `l` *are* crooked. You can correct that by letting TikZ calculate the coordinates itsself: define e.g. `starta` (where the line for `a` starts), and let it go to the point where `starta` and `ldimension2` meet with `starta -| ldimension2`:

```
\draw[<->] ($(adimension.south)+(0,0.5)$) coordinate (starta) -- (starta-|ldimension2) node[midway,anchor=south]{$a$};
\draw[<->] ($(ldimension1.south)+(0,0.5)$) coordinate (startl1) -- (startl1-|ldimension2) node[midway,anchor=south]{$\ell$};
```

Regarding the bar height: each node has an `inner sep` parameter, which is the separation between the content inside the `{}` and the border. Even though your node is empty, and `minimum height` is set to zero, the rectangle is at least `2*inner sep` high. To make it smaller, we can set `inner sep` to `0pt` and set the height *exactly* with `minimum height`:

```
\tikzstyle{bar}=[fill=lightgray,
                draw=black,
                minimum width=6cm,
                minimum height=0.2cm,
                inner sep=0pt,
                anchor=west]
```

[image: result]